# Parsing JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am working on a project and my JSON file I am getting from the website does not have any (key) for me to start my parsing from. So, when I use the line in the code , `let userInfo = swiftyJSON[].arrayValue` I will get all the information from the JSON file. My problem is that I need to parse it further so I can fill a UITableView and I cant seem to parse it to be more specific.

*This is the code from my JSON*

```
let externalURL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

func getJSON(){
            let url = URL(string: externalURL)
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            let session = URLSession(configuration:URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                    let userInfo = swiftyJSON[].arrayValue
                    print(userInfo)
    }
                else{
                    print("There was an error")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: `My problem is that I need to parse it further so I can fill a UITableView and I cant seem to parse it to be more specific.` We don't have enough information to help you.  What is the JSON schema.  How do you want your parsing to be "more specific?"

Comment: I would like to get only a few bits of information from the JSON, (i.e. name, phone, and e-mail). `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    }]`

Comment: If you check out the URL [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users] you can view the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point:

```
let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
if let userInfo = swiftyJSON.array {
   for user in userInfo {
     print(user["name"].string, user["email"].string, user["phone"].string)
     if let address = user["address"].dictionary {
         print(address["city"]?.string)
     }
   }
}
```

All printed values are optionals.

Comment: Thank you. So how would I add that information into a `UITableView, UITableViewCell`?

Comment: That depends on your data source model (dictionary, custom struct / class or whatever).

Comment: The above code is putting it into a dictionary or is it still in an array right now. Dictionaries are easier correct?

Comment: How do I get the Optionals from the above code in a tableview. My table view is in the second screen of my UI. I'm having issues with getting the table view controller in my class on the original view controller.